# Is there a way to draw simple shapes with javascript in a browser without canvas?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, canvas, browser

I am working on a C# chat client that needs to have a sending icon when a message is being sent.  The icon cannot be an image because of the nature of my program.  All messages are displayed in a web browser control that is constantly being modified.  Is there any way to draw a circle that could change color or size slightly without relying on html5/canvas, or something like flash/java.  I cannot guarantee that any of those frameworks will exist on the client computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode contains a circle (●), so it will behave like a text element. You can size it and color it accordingly. This will also work with older browsers.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/index.htm

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Simply use a `<div>` element and style it. A square with equally rounded corners becomes a circle.

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/E4B5p/

```
.circle {
    moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dominic's Method will work, another route is to use something like SVG.

```
   **<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black"
  stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
  </svg> **
```

Both are good, SVG is easier to animate if you fancied that

Answer (score 1):

You can pure css to draw simple forms, using some smart tricks: see [css poligons](http://tantek.com/CSS/Examples/polygons.html)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, circles can be drawn using CSS3.  By defining your circles in classes it's easy to change the nature of the circle using javascript, like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
.circle {width:4px; height:4px; border-radius:4px; border:2px solid green; background:green;}
.red {border: 2px solid red; background-color:red;}
</style>

<div id="target" class="circle" onclick="document.getElementById('target').className += ' red';"></div>
```

Note that none of the solutions provided so far are supported in IE.  To support CSS circles in IE you'll need to use a library like pie:
http://css3pie.com/